# Snapshot scaled UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview, rendering

Snapshotting a `UIView` using `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` and a variety of other approaches including the `render(in:)` and `drawHierarchy(in: afterScreenUpdates:)` functions works great when you need to render a regular ol' view.

I have been unable to get any of this working properly when trying to draw a scaled `UIView` hierarchy. The view in question is a `UIScrollView`'s content & zoom view.

The view and its superviews refuse to do any transforms just before the snapshot that would fix the scaling problem. The result is that the snapshot either looks like:

- A) an unfortunately cropped view, with its origin in the upper left (as expected on iOS), but then only expanding to the un-transformed "bounds" of the view. If the view happens to have no zoom or scale transform this is okay, but that rarely if ever happens.
- B) an oversized view with big black borders that match the transformed "frame" of the view. I'm assuming this happens due to some weirdness with snapshotting a scaled view's frame.

**TL;DR**: Can't snapshot / render a `UIView` after it has been scaled and zoomed by a `UIScrollView`, despite attempts to transform or redraw before snapshotting.

**Edit**: see below for an example of this frustrating behavior.

1. The result of snapshotting the view (**actual result**) [image: UIView Snapshot Result]
2. The **expected result** (unable to reproduce using CoreGraphics) [image: Expected result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To draw the complete content view of a scroll view you could use something like:

```
@IBAction func onClear(_ sender: Any) {
    self.targetImageView.image = nil
}

@IBAction func onSnapshot(_ sender: Any) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.contentView.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
    if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
        self.contentView.layer.render(in: context)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        self.targetImageView.image = image
    } else {
        self.targetImageView.image = nil
    }
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}
```

**Test**

In the upper area there is a scroll view with activated zoom (maximumZoomScale = 5). In the lower area there is only a simple UIImageView. If one taps on the button with the label "snap", `onSnapshot` is called and the lower UIImageView is filled with the snapshot image. With the button 'clear' UIImageView's image is set to nil.

[image: snapshot demo]

Comment: Thank you! This isn't *exactly* the problem I'm trying to solve, although it is headed in the right direction and is helpful... The issue is that when I attempt to snapshot the *entire* content of the scroll view and the content is zoomed (as in the right screenshot), funny things happen and I'm unable to get the full render of the content (as seen in your left screenshot).

Comment: I've updated the answer. Now the content view of the scroll view is snapshotted. I have also added a clear action to ensure that the snapshot image is deleted. Then in the demo I zoom in and move the area and take snapshots. The content view is displayed correctly. Is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to achieve, and your code / solution is exactly what I'd expect would work. But for some reason I'm still seeing the result above (see the edit to my question)

Comment: Update: your solution works great, as expected, I just needed to adjust the bounds' size and multiply by the transform values, then set the `opaque` and `clipsToBounds` flags to `false`!!

Comment: @SamSpencer How did you go about adjusting the bounds of the view? Can you edit your questions with some of those details?